# How to autoscroll in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, autoscroll

How do you autoscroll the scrollbar in C# (and not permanently)?

Like for example, when I update something in the object in which the scroll bar is assigned, I want it to automatically scroll to the rightmost side.

I tried:

```
pnlGraph.HorizontalScroll.Value = pnlGraph.HorizontalScroll.Maximum;
```

but it becomes permanent to the Maximum value.

Any answers to this?

Comment: It shouldn't be permanent. Are you doing this on mouse-down  or some other repeating event?

Comment: Yes, I placed it inside the paint event (which I also call repeatedly).

This is because the size of the object which the scroll bar is assigned is incrementing.

Comment: Are you using WinForms? Btw scrolling in winforms(at least for some controls) has a bug, where the getter and setter use a differing sign convention.

Comment: Yes, I am using WinForms. The problem is solved. Thanks though. ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't assign the scroll value in the paint event. Doing that ensures that the max value is set every time it is painted, so it remains 'permanent', as you say.

Comment: That solves my problem. I feel ashamed for overlooking it. Thanks a lot! ^_^

Comment: Don't forget to accept and upvote answers that work for you! (IMO both answers here :) )